# How to format currency for a textfield in a UIAlertview

Tags: ios, ios7, ios6, uialertview, uialertviewdelegate

I want to add format currency for a textfield in a UIAlertview. However, I don't have any solution about this. Can you help me if you know solution?

Thanks

Comment: what type of research have you done already before you asked a community to solve your problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to properly format currency on ios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11787759/how-to-properly-format-currency-on-ios)

Comment: I could have chosen any other posts which is about the formatted currencies, like e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105227/is-there-a-simple-way-to-format-currency-into-string-in-ios

Answer (score 1):

```
 NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
 formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle;
 NSString *cash = [formatter stringFromNumber:@5];

[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:cash message:cash delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil ] show];
```

Comment: This is not my idea. Ex: I enter the value from keyboard: 200 then textfield of UIAlertview will show: $200

Comment: Use UITextField Delegate.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html

Comment: I know use it in a normal textfield but I don't know the way to use it in textfield of **Alertview**.

Comment: What style has your alert? Is it UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput? If yes do this and use UITextField Delegate.
textfield =  [alert textFieldAtIndex: 0];
textfield.delegate = self;

Comment: it does not work although I added UITextField  *textfield = [alert textFieldAtIndex: 0];
    textfield.delegate = self; to viewDidload

Comment: As I talked above, I added 2 lines:  UITextField *textfield = [alert textFieldAtIndex: 0]; textfield.delegate = self; to viewDidload. Then I put NSlog (@"go to delegate"); in - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField. However, it does not go into this method when I click Return button of the keyboard

Comment: //create alert view :alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Please input the Cash" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
            alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
            [textfield setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad];
            [textfield becomeFirstResponder];
            [alert show];

Comment: ah I knew. I alloc alertView outside viewDidLoad